# How to store variables: Privileged method, static property

Tags: javascript, performance, global-variables, scope

Instead of just saying:

```
var thing = timeConsumingMethod();
```

I have my variable hidden in a method like so:

```
function _thing() {
    var thing = timeConsumingMethod() );
    return thing;
    }
```

It gets called a number of times. I'm concerned that I'm made things very inefficient. I assume it calls timeConsumingMethod every time (which is unneeded, it's always the same) I call "_thing()" to get my variable.

How do I manage these types of variables in simple efficient way? Is something like this a solution?:

```
function _thing() {
    return _thing.thing 
    }
    _thing.thing = timeConsumingMethod();
```

Basically, i want the protection of a function and to (ideally0 access my variable using _thing() or something similar, but I only want timeConsumingMethod to run once.

edit: tried this, doesn't work either:

```
function _thingy() { 
var thing = timeConsumingMethod();
}
_thingy.test = function() {
return( _thingy.thing)
}
```

Comment: My suggested solution doesn't work actually.

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.seejohncode.com/2012/03/31/lazy-properties-in-javascript/

Comment: @ArturUdod Yeah. I tried to impliment that (without the laze part) and property was set as something. But i couldn't get to be the result of the timeConsumingMethod. How would you fill the brackets of prop?

Comment: i think I would make a class with a getter if i was doing this in c#.

Comment: Pls, see my answer, maybe that will do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
function SomethingTimeConsuming() { ... }

function LazyThing(sourceFunction) {

    this.sourceFunction = sourceFunction;
    this.value = null;

    this.Value = function() {
        if ( this.value == null) this.value = sourceFunction();
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YSAjJ/

Output:

```
[14:20:20.079] Calling time-consuming function  *(1 time)
```

Comment: Please provide at least the gist of the link here in the answer, or make it a comment. Link-only answers are prone to go out of date and become useless.

Comment: @NathanCooper, how do you anticipate changing the value if it's encapsulated and only available by calling getter-function?

Comment: So if I go: var value = thing.Value();   value2 = thing.Value(); etc it doesn't call my function again ever? great.

Comment: If it's supposed to be changed then you might want to add some logic to LazyThing or just re-instantiate it by `thing = new LazyThing(anotherSourceFunction);`

Comment: yes, `thing.Value()` will return the cached result, that's what you were asking for, weren't you?

Comment: @Artur Udod  Re(how do you anticipate...). That was the original plan. To have something i couldn't change.